# Getting incorrect values with COUNT() in OPTIONAL MATCH query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Ok so here is my data model:

```
(User)-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(Account)
(Location)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(Account)
(User)-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(Location)
```

In my database there is 1 account, 1 location and 16 users. Each user is `:ASSIGNED_TO` the account and also `:ASSIGNED_TO` the location. The location `:BELONGS_TO` the account.

I'm trying to select a specific account by id and also return the number of users and locations for that account. Here is my query:

```
MATCH (account:Account)
WHERE account.id = '123456'
WITH account
OPTIONAL MATCH (location:Location)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(account)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user:User)-[:ASSIGNED_TO]->(account)
RETURN account, count(location) as locationCount, count(user) as userCount
```

The result is the `account`, a `userCount = 16 (correct)` and a `locationCount = 16 (incorrect; should be 1)`. If I add `distinct` to the location count, `count(distinct location)`, I get the correct result (1) and if I remove the `OPTIONAL MATCH` for the users, I also get a location count of 1. I know it has something to do with the users having a relationship to the account and the location but I'm just trying to understand why the query without distinct doesn't work. Also, is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a bit tricky. This is the query rewritten to show the pattern you are looking for :

```
MATCH (account:Account)
WHERE account.id = '123456'
MATCH (location:Location)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(account)<-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(user:User)
RETURN account, count (location), count (user)
```

There's one account in the middle, but you don't know what the numbers are on each side. The **resultset** will contain all matches for the pattern (happens to be 16, but there could have been more locations and users assigned to multiple locations). So actually **neither** count is correct (you just get lucky for the users).

```
MATCH (account:Account)
WHERE account.id = '123456'
MATCH (location:Location)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(account)<-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(user:User)
RETURN account, count (DISTINCT location), count (DISTINCT user)
```

DISTINCT solves the problem. Aggregated by account (there is only one so no real aggregation happens) there are 16 locations in the resultset. DISTINCT makes sure you only count the unique ones. And the same DOES apply for the users too !

Take a look at this query to see the difference :

```
MATCH (account:Account)
WHERE account.id = '123456'
MATCH (location:Location)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(account)
RETURN account.id as id, "location count" as type, count(location) as ct
UNION
MATCH (account:Account)
WHERE account.id = '123456'
MATCH (account)<-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(user:User)
RETURN account.id as id, "user count" as type, count(user) as ct
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Tom, thanks for the reply. The reason I had the query written as it was (separate OPTIONAL MATCH statements for users & locations) was because it is dynamically generated. I have args of 'withUsers' and 'withLocations' that can be set independently so I may have one or the other, both or neither in the final query. I get that 'distinct' works, I'm just trying to understand why a count of 16 locations is returned when there is only one in the database. I guess it has something to do with the relationship to the 16 users but I just don't know why it is the case.

Comment: It's the number of matches for the complete pattern (grouped by account) that is determining your counts, neither (!!!) users or locations. If it would have found 20 hits your counts would have been twenty.

Answer (score 0):

If you view your result in row instead of graph, you can see that there are actually 16 rows of data. Each row will contain `location`, `count(location)` is actually returning the number of lines that has `location`.

I prefer using `distinct` for removing duplicates. We have service in production and we are using `distinct` in a similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem and it helped to think of it from an RDBMS perspective.

Consider a table of Users like so (I'll use 4 for my example):

```
Users
-----
u1
u2
u3
u4
```

And consider 2 tables of Locations and Accounts each (with one record each, as in your case):

```
Locations
---------
loc1

Accounts
--------
acc1
```

Now, when Neo4j evaluates a query like `MATCH (location:Location)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(account)<-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(user:User)`, it starts looking for `User` nodes, and `Location` nodes, and follows relationships inwards to `Account` nodes, where it then performs a join. So, to break that query into intermediate queries, it would look like: `MATCH (location:Location)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(account)` and `MATCH (account)<-[:ASSIGNED_TO]-(user:User)`. Evaluating those 2 queries would give us something like the following tables:

```
Location-Account
----------------
loc1 | acc1

Account-User
------------
u1 | acc1
u2 | acc1
u3 | acc1
u4 | acc1
```

Finally, Neo4j performs a join on the intermediate results, to return something like the following combined table:

```
User-Account-Location
---------------------
u1 | acc1 | loc1
u2 | acc1 | loc1
u3 | acc1 | loc1
u4 | acc1 | loc1
```

`count(location)` as per this table would be 4, while `count(DISTINCT(location))` would be 1 :)